# Auto start drawable animation in dialogFragment

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to create a custom loading dialog that displays an animated "loading wheel", but I cant seem to figure out which method to call `AnimationDrawable.start()` in order to automatically start the animation in the `DialogFragment`.

The only documentation I found addresses calling it in `onWindowFocusChanged()`.  Does anyone know what is the appropriate method is to call in a `DialogFragment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  Turns out what I was using was correct all along.  The reason it wasn't showing was because the ImageView in the layout was being covered by a TextView.

To start an animation in a DialogFragment, override the onStart() method of the DialogFragment as it is typically called when the activity's onStart() method is called.